# Future<int> to int in flutter, dart

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I'm using flutter moor to store data in my flutter app. And I get data from the database and it returns a Future. I broke down the list to get a single value and now I have a Future. What I need to do is convert Future to int for comparing the value of Future with a static int value. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: If you don’t know what futures are I recommend following a tutorial on dart before attempting flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A future is an object rapresenting a potential value (or an error) that could be available in the future.
It is a common object if you are working with asyncronous programming.

Read here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html

You could simply prepare a callback for when the value will be available by using:

```
Future<int> future = Future(foo);  // Result of foo() as a future.
future.then((int value) => bar(value))
      .catchError((e) => 499);
```

Or use await operator.

If you need to modify the graphics according to the result, you could use a FutureBuilder.

Comment: FutureBuilder worked for me. I had some UI changes after getting the results. Thank you for the help.